# Is there any advantage to learning C first?

Tags: c, objective-c

I've got a little bit of history with programming, having gotten my start with Visual Basic. I let it slide as a hobby from a little after VB6 up until just a year or so ago when I got on the iPhone bandwagon, when I decided to take up Objective-C programming.

I now have what I feel to be an intermediate level of knowledge on the language, but I can't help but feel that there's a substantial gap in where my knowledge is, given that there seems to be a substantial bit of the language I don't feel I understand.

Would I benefit from reviewing the underlying C structure, or would I be better served from continuing to practice solely in Objective-C whilst reviewing the documentation for various features?

**Edit:** Though I've accepted the first answer given, more insight is always appreciated from those with supplementary or opposing views.

Comment: Depends on what exactly the substantial bit of the language you don't understand is.

Comment: Though I can't put my finger on any specific part that I think I'm lacking, it normally ends up being in an exercise that I'll be following. For example, I'll be led through a method and how to go about performing a task, and then told that they're gonna have to use a C-level function to get it done, and I'll have no idea why it's being done, or how they came to that conclusion.

Comment: "what language you should learn next" type questions are [discouraged per site FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: I'm not actually asking which language should I learn next. I'm trying to figure out if it would be beneficial to learn C for the basic foundation of programming in the C language sub/supersets, or if it's satisfactory enough to learn each language on its own.

Comment: the learning is okay, but active use of C for time long enough may shape you mind in a way, not suited for programming in superset.

Comment: True, and that's another opinion that I've read. That is, procedural vs. object-oriented programming types, which is what caused me to overlook reading into the C language in the first place. But it just seems that more and more often, the different lessons I find end up diving back into C functions.

Comment: C is a procedural language. If you just want to learn about the procedural paradigm I would advise you to learn a cleaner language like Pascal: Pascal has been used extensively in real applications but was specifically designed for teaching (therefore Pascal is less hacker-oriented than C). However, if you need to work on some real project in an area that specifically requires C, then you can go ahead and learn C.

Comment: There's no specific need for C per se, but it just seems like the platforms that I want to develop for have C at their core (e.g., C# and Objective-C for Windows and Mac, respectively). So I'm just trying to ensure that I've got the foundation required to have a better understanding of those particular languages.

Comment: @Terrance Shaw: C has a high practical relevance because, besides being at the core of language like Objective-C and C++) it is often used as an interface between languages. E.g. AFAIK there is a C-interface for Java, Haskell, and many other languages. So even if nowadays not many people develop their applications directly in C, C is practically very important.

Comment: I asked a related question on SO: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858820/learning-c-for-objective-c>

Comment: @qegal Ah, so you did. Very insightful answers there, and I could've (should've?) looked there before posting here. But SO has always struck me as more of the actual code solution side of the house. Either way, thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features of Objective-C are more or less a Superset of the features of C.

So, for me, the answer is yes.

You'll be learning the most critical concepts of Objective-C and most will find procedural programming a lot simpler and [less surprising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) than similar solutions solved with object oriented programming.

You have a much better chance of understanding all of the concepts in C than you do in Objective-C.  Assembly language  is another good language with few surprises and few features.

You might have trouble solving a complex problem when you use lower level languages, but you'll actually be able to learn and understand them **much** easier.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your very clear and concise answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you don't understand about Obj-C.  If you feel you have a good grip on the OO side, but struggle with things like pointers or array semantics, then by all means you want to explore the lower-level C side of things.

If you're struggling with OO concepts or message passing or the runtime, then learning C won't help you at all.

Comment: I think I've got a fairly good grasp on the OO part of Objective-C, there's just some... finer nuances?... of the language that elude me. Been skimming over "The C Programming Language", and even from the beginning, it seems to be filling in some of the gaps.